# How Float divs like twitter?

Tags: html, css

I have three `<div>` elements on my HTML page:

```
    <div id="main">

        <div id="bodyright" >
            here Right
        </div>

        <div id="bodycenter" >
            Here Center
        </div>

        <div id="bodyleft" >
            here left
        </div>

    </div>
```

file css

Note that the right-most div is listed first, then the center div, then the left.

1. When the page is zoomed normally (100%), I want the three div elements next to each other, like this example: http://jsfiddle.net/hqak756s/
2. When the page is zoomed in, I want the center div next to the right div and the left div below the right div. Currently, it's showing the left div underneath the center div.

How can I get this working?

Comment: read this first .... http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: You should really consult these docs firsthand: http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-grid-system/ , http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp , http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/  <- better this link first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using boostrap for these things, however I created something for you nonetheless:

```html
<style>
.table {
    width:100%;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: gray;
}
.tbody{
    width:inherit;
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
.tr{
    width:inherit;
    display: table-row;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-color: inherit;
}
.td{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .td{display:block;}
}
</style>
<div class="table">
    <div class="tbody">
        <div class="tr">
            <div class="td" style="background-color:green;">Left</div>
            <div class="td" style="background-color:red;">Centre</div>
            <div class="td" style="background-color:blue;">Right</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can probably tell I used a table to begin with, but it's behaviour was strange so I just created a bunch of divs. Not very efficient but it works. Note that this is basically a template for you: I haven't really stylised it around your code.